# Django, syntax for insering Javascript to template

Tags: javascript, django, bokeh

I would like to embed Bokeh plot in Django template using Json output.
http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html#json-items

Json output is ready for query in database. Plot should be rendered to div with specific ID.

Documentation says to use Json output in template with following code function:

```
item = JSON.parse(item_text);
Bokeh.embed.embed_item(item);
```

Please advise the correct syntax for use in template:

```
<div id="title"></div>

<script>
function(response) { return item = JSON.parse( {{plot_json}} ); }
function(item) { Bokeh.embed.embed_item(item); }
</script>
```

View file:

```
def home(request):
    plot_json = Price_Charts.objects.using('llweb').values('timeframe_1h').filter(symbol_pair='ETH')
    context = {
    'plot_json': plot_json
    }
    return render(request, "home.html", context)
```

Comment: You should show the view that is sending `plot_json` to the template.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Bokeh, but I know that you need to ensure that the JSON object is read correctly in the Django template as JavaScript and not auto-escaped. Give [autoescape off](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#autoescape) a try along with the Bokeh '[then](http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html#json-items)' syntax.

```
<div id="title"></div>

<script>        
fetch('/plot') 
    .then(function(response) { 
         {% autoescape off %}
             return item = JSON.parse( {{plot_json}} ); 
        {% autoescape on %}
    })
    .then(function(item) { Bokeh.embed.embed_item(item); })
</script>
```

Comment: Easier to do `{{ plot_json|safe }}`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this simplified jinja2 example can help you (tested on Bokeh v1.0.4). Run it as:

```
python myapp.py
```

The file and directory structure:

```
myapp
   |
   +---myapp.py
   +---templates
        +---index.html
```

myapp.py

```
import io
import json
import jinja2
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc
from bokeh.embed import json_item
from bokeh.resources import CDN

plot = figure()
plot.line(np.arange(10), np.random.random(10))
curdoc().add_root(plot)

renderer = jinja2.Environment(loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(['templates']), trim_blocks = True)
html = renderer.get_template('index.html').render(resources = CDN.render(), item_json_object = json.dumps(json_item(plot)))

filename = 'json_items.html'
with io.open(filename, mode = 'w', encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
    f.write(html)
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
{{ resources }}
</head>
<body>
<div id="myplot"></div>
<script>
    Bokeh.embed.embed_item({{ item_json_object }}, "myplot");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It seems that the result of `json.dumps(json_item(plot)`) passed to the template is already a JSON object so you cannot use `JSON.parse()` on it. Or make sure you really pass a string object to this function.

The [Bokeh documentation](http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html#json-items) you refer to points to [an example](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/1.0.4/examples/embed/json_item.py) which is different from this one in the sense the plots data is loaded dynamically using JS fetch() method at page loading time in browser while here the plots data is attached to the page at template rendering time.